# Power BI reports are not refreshing because of invalid gateway credentials

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-datagateway

My reports on Power BI service are connected to a data source which is a sql server. I added this to a gateway and scheduled a refresh every morning. I use my microsoft credentials for the connection. Now it's failing after I changed my windows password, any idea how to fix this?

Error message:

[image]

Comment: In Dataset setting, you can change credentials under `Data source credentials`

Comment: It says 'Unable to test connection to data source. Try the credentials again.' There are no options where I can change the credentials.

Comment: make sure to take control of dataset if it's not already taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/gateways and change the settings of the connection and change the Authentication settings:

[image]

Comment: Strange that I'm not able to save the new settings